# Getting Javascript to show HTML in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this site I've been working on here: http://www.replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/xmas/index.php

When you hover over the first photo at the top, a voting box appears. Now if you click on the photo it displays the 'By whom' name and 2 numbers (the vote results). Both the photo thumbnail and the enlarged lightbox share the same HTML content as each other.

What I don't understand is why the enlarged box doesn't display the HTML properly, just the 2 numbers from the voting element rather than the voting element itself.

If you look at the source, you can see down the page in the code is the javascript and I can't figure out what I need to change to the JS in order to make HTML display on the larger view?

Here is an example of what the markup is for each thumbnail you click:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-largesrc="images/large/1.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>By Tim Morgan <?php echo ThumbsUp::item('1')->template('thumbs_up_down') ?></span></a>
```

As you can see, there is the thumb source and the large source as well as the voting function.

Comment: You seem to use `.text` to copy the name/votes. What about using `.html`?

Comment: Just tried changing to .html. Now if you look, it actually shows the HTML as text :/

Comment: I mean setting with `.html` as well ;)

Comment: Think it may have worked. Have another look at the same URL. Seems a bit intermittent though, sometimes shows, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: It seems `.tmpl` doesn't accept HTML. Could you try removing the `else` clause on line 371? I think the HTML is then always set.

Comment: Think that seems to have worked :) Stick an answer in the section below and I'll accept it to get you some kudos points! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you have to set HTML with the `.html` method - currently you're converting the whole to text and then setting text.

Secondly, it looks like `.tmpl` does not like HTML. If you also set the HTML the first time (when doing `.tmpl`), it should always work.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the forms so they exist on the previews.